# How to compare two columns for a string and replace the string case in one column to other?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, pattern-matching

I have two columns Sentences and Updates. I want to match each words in Updates Column at the end of a Url with corresponding Sentences word case and replace it with the case of the word in Sentences.

I have no clue how to go about this comparison any help is appreciated. 
The actual data has 43k rows with different Url's.

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'Updates': ['The new abc.com/Line','Its a abc.com/bright and abc.com/Sunny Day','abc.com/smartphone have taken our the abc.com/WORLD','abc.com/GLOBAL Warming is abc.com/Reaching its abc.com/peak'],
     'Sentences': ['The new line','Its a bright and sunny day','Smartphone have taken our the World','GLOBAL Warming is reaching its Peak ']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Current O/P:

```
Sentences           Updates
The new line            The new abc.com/Line

Its a bright and sunny day          Its a abc.com/bright and abc.com/Sunny Day

Smartphone have taken our the World         abc.com/smartphone have taken our the abc.com/WORLD

GLOBAL Warming is reaching its Peak             abc.com/GLOBAL Warming is abc.com/Reaching its abc.com/peak
```

```
Expected O/P:

Sentences           Updates
The new line            The new abc.com/line

Its a bright and sunny day          Its a abc.com/bright and abc.com/sunny day

Smartphone have taken our the World         abc.com/Smartphone have taken our the abc.com/World

GLOBAL Warming is reaching its Peak             abc.com/GLOBAL Warming is abc.com/reaching its abc.com/Peak
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re`

Code:

```
import re

dict1 = {
    'Sentences': [
        'The new line',
        'Its a bright and sunny day',
        'Smartphone have taken our the World',
        'GLOBAL Warming is reaching its Peak '
    ],
    'Updates': [
        'The new abc.com/Line',
        'Its a abc.com/bright and abc.com/Sunny Day',
        'abc.com/smartphone have taken our the abc.com/WORLD',
        'abc.com/GLOBAL Warming is abc.com/Reaching its abc.com/peak'
    ]
 }
for sentence, update in zip(dict1['Sentences'], dict1['Updates']):
    urls = [x.split("/")[-1] for x in update.split() if "/" in x]
    for url in urls:
        update = (re.sub(url, re.search(url, sentence, re.IGNORECASE).group(), update, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

    print(f"{sentence}\t{update}")
```

Output:

```
The new line    The new abc.com/line
Its a bright and sunny day  Its a abc.com/bright and abc.com/sunny Day
Smartphone have taken our the World abc.com/Smartphone have taken our the abc.com/World
GLOBAL Warming is reaching its Peak     abc.com/GLOBAL Warming is abc.com/reaching its abc.com/Peak
```

Comment: Thanks @outflanker I will give this a try.

Comment: @ABY: Please accept the answer if this was helpful! :)  [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)